# Personalise jgitflow maven plugin

Tags: git, maven, maven-plugin, git-flow, jgitflow-maven-plugin

i started using jgitflow in a java project, and i want to achieve something like below:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
   <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <noDeploy>true</noDeploy>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>execution1</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>hotfix-start</goal>
            <goal>release-start</goal>
            <goal>feature-start</goal>
            <goal>feature-finish</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <allowSnapshots>true</allowSnapshots>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
      <execution>
         <id>execution2</id>
         <goals>
            <goal>hotfix-finish</goal>
            <goal>release-finish</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <allowSnapshots>false</allowSnapshots>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

when i start a new hotfix i should be able to create it, but i got this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:hotfix-start (default-cli) on project jgitflow-test: Error starting hotfix: Error starting hotfix: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://gitlab.audaxis.com/compiere-client/client-xxx/jgitflow-test.git: not authorized -> [Help 1]
```

How can i fix this ?

and thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add your credentials into the configuration section o fix the "not authorized" error

```
<configuration>
    <useReleaseProfile>true</useReleaseProfile>
    <noDeploy>false</noDeploy>
    <pushReleases>false</pushReleases>
    <pullDevelop>true</pullDevelop>
    <pullMaster>true</pullMaster>
    <scmCommentPrefix>RELEASE:</scmCommentPrefix>
    <allowUntracked>true</allowUntracked>
    <username>${git.user}</username>
    <password>${git.password}</password>
</configuration>
```